# How to print a drive document with Google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-print

An example of what I would like to do is print 10 copies of a PDF that lives in Google Drive using a script.  I learned today about Site's Gadgets and that may be how we implement this script and yesterday we enabled Cloud Printing to our printers.

I found a similar this question posted already from 2012: [google app script print button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194291/google-app-script-print-button/11198367#11198367)

Apparently when this question was asked GAS and Cloud Printing didn't work? or wasn't supported or wasn't available... I'm not sure.

Is this possible?

I apologize since this is new to me and I don't know the google lingo well enough yet.

Thank you!

Andy

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do what you want directly in google app script but this might be useful:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via Google Script. This [post](https://ctrlq.org/code/20061-google-cloud-print-with-apps-script) by Amit Agarwal explains how.

The key is making sure that you have a printer set up with Google Print. I have a printer with no wifi capability but is connected to an outdated Mac that exclusively runs Google print.