# How to print documents and spreedsheets from google drive

Tags: printing, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I can't seem to find information on how to print files through google app script.

I found an answer in this website but it doesn't work, I think it's because it's 3 years old and google script has had some changes.

[google app script print button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194291/google-app-script-print-button/11198367)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print directly from GAS (I've searched far and wide), as described in the post that you linked. However it is possible to create a downloadable document with the desired content and then pass that blob off to the client for downloading (depending on wether you're still working in GAS or a web app environment).

Personally, I felt that it was a headache to deal with how each browser deals with downloading blobs. Therefore I usually go one of these two routes: provide a public downloadable link from the drive of the owner of the script and then push it to the user to download, OR just email the document to the user and let their email client handle downloading the blob.

Alternatively, if this is an add-on, you can make it so that the document is downloaded directly to the users own drive and just inform them where the document will be located.