# Google Apps Script print sheet with margins

Tags: google-apps-script, printing, google-sheets

There is a nice GAS script to print a Google sheet in [google app script print button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194291/google-app-script-print-button/30779555#30779555)

As discussed on the Google Cloud Connect (https://www.cloudconnect.goog/message/77627), we are trying to identify a way to control the margins.

There is also a similar question over on the Google Product Forums at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/DQxnJwoDn0c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was also reported in this [thread](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885). I suggest to file a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) for this.

Answer (score 3):

You might find this script useful.

I think that it might answer your question on the margins plus it has a few other helpful settings that you can play with.

```
function printPdf() {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
    var pdfOpts = '&size=A3&fzr=true&portrait=false&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=true&sheetnames=true&pagenumbers=true&attachment=false&gid='+gid;
    var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(300).setHeight(100);
    app.setTitle('Your Print Preview is Ready');
    var link = app.createAnchor('Open Print Preview', url).setTarget('_new');
    app.add(link);
    ss.show(app);
}
```

See also: [Printing a sheet to PDF](https://plus.google.com/u/0/115432608459317672860/posts/DQTbozyTsKk?cfem=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your first link uses the UiApp which has been depricated but I think I'd look in the following if you still wish to use it.

```
var pdfOpts = '&size=A4&fzr=false&portrait=false&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&shee        tnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid='+gid;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is (currently) neither possible through App Script API ...nor the Macro Recorder

therefore, I'd suggest to utilize some Chrome extension, alike [Automation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/automation/jldomlpgobfdlloikpngnjbdidonfjhj).

the key-codes to open the page setup dialog and enter the desired values and then proceed to hit the `Next` button, should be about alike this: `<Alt> + F`, `P`, (select margins, then select custom numbers, then select the top margin entry field, that can be reached by `<Tab>`, `<Cursor Down>` and `<Space>`)... and then `0.25"`, `<Tab>`, `0.25"`, `<Tab>`, `0.25"`, `<Tab>`, `0.25"` ... `<Tab>`, `<Tab>`, `<Enter>`.

from within a spreadsheet (and not even from within client-side JavaScript), without any browser extension, which can send key-codes, there is no access to these properties - because otherwise scripts could easily mess up custom local printer settings.