# how to to print a google sheet range from a google script function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to create a google script that prints a certain range of cells from an active spreadsheet. The purpose of this is to automatize my process of printing and saving info related to invoices and similar documents.

Comment: Apps Script doesn't run in your browser, so it can't access your peripherals like a printer. Review PDF generation / export, and creating files in Drive. Or write a sidebar with `HtmlService` and use normal browser JavaScript with async communication.

Comment: I´ll try something else then! thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11194291/1595451