Improve Google Apps Script function for downloading file from Google Drive to initiate the download quicker
My goal is to improve the Google Apps Script function used to automatically download a zip file from Google Drive. This function is assigned to a button in Google Sheets.
I would like the function to initiate the download quicker.
To create the function, I have adapted the answers from this similar question.
This is my version of Tanaike's second answer:
function downloadFile() {
  const url   = ENTER_DOWNLOAD_URL;

  // Open a dialog and run Javascript for downloading the file.
  const str  = '<script>window.location.href="' + url + '"</script>';
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str).setHeight(1).setWidth(1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Downloading...");

  // This is used for closing the dialog.
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
  const closeHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>google.script.host.close()</script>").setHeight(1).setWidth(1);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(closeHtml, "Downloading...");
}

This is my version of TheMaster's answer:
function downloadFileToDesktop() {
  const url   = ENTER_DOWNLOAD_URL;

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      '<a href ="' + url +
        '">Click here</a> to download, if download did not start automatically' +
        '<script> \
        var a = document.querySelector("a"); \
        a.addEventListener("click",()=>{setTimeout(google.script.host.close,5000)}); \
        a.click(); \
        </script>'
    ).setHeight(50),
    'Downloading...'
  );
}

In both answers, I had to increase the Utilities.sleep() and setTimeout() to 5 seconds for the download to work, and I don't really understand why.
TheMaster's original answer was much faster. Below is that function with very little editing, I've simply changed the url but left in the anchor tag's download attribute and base64 encoding. It downloads immediately, but it is not possible to expand the zip file because it is an unsupported format, obviously.
Once I've simplified this function to the version above, so that it can download the zip file correctly, it takes five seconds to initiate the download. Why?
Ideally, I would like to adapt TheMaster's answer to download a zip file but without losing the speed.

1.1MB = file size of download using downloadFileToDesktop()
870KB = file size of download using downloadOriginal()

function downloadOriginal() {
  const url = ENTER_DOWNLOAD_URL;
  let val   = 'FILENAME';//custom zip name here 
  val += '.zip';
  //can't download with a different filename directly from server
  //download and remove content-disposition header and serve as a dataURI
  //Use anchor tag's download attribute to provide a custom filename
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      '<a target ="_blank" download="' +
        val +
        '" href = "data:application/pdf;base64,' +
        Utilities.base64Encode(res.getContent()) +
        '">Click here</a> to download, if download did not start automatically' +
        '<script> \
        var a = document.querySelector("a"); \
        a.addEventListener("click",()=>{setTimeout(google.script.host.close,10)}); \
        a.click(); \
        </script>'
    ).setHeight(50),
    'Downloading ZIP...'
  );
}

Further references and other similar questions:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getDownloadUrl()
Download all Google sheets charts in one shot?
Initiate a download
Download PDF file from google drive AppScript Google Sheet
How to download created csv file using Google Apps Script?
Zip all files in a folder and download the zipped file


Get the url and use the answer(s) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215898/how-to-down

This question is similar to: How to download single sheet as PDF to my local device directly (not export to Google Drive)?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Question updated, thank you for similar question link

This question now includes multiple questions in one. Please ask only one question per post.

I've re-edited the question to ask only one question @doubleunary and I will make separate posts for my other questions. The first of which on access-token can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79141799/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-access-token-parameter-when-downloading-a-file-fro

What's the size of the file? If it is bigger then it is expected to take longer to download the file.

1.1 MB @TheMaster what I found curious is that if I used your function for downloading a PDF, with the base64encoding and the name change, but simply changed the URL to the ZIP file, it was really quick, the file size was about 870KB. The file was useless, of course, a compressed ZIP file! I wondered if there was something with your original function that was somehow quicker.

@TheMaster I've edited my answer (again!) to include your original function with minimal editing, which initiates the download really qiuckly

@TopMarx If that answers your question, you may add it as an self-answer in the answer box below. See [answer].

It downloads immediately, but it is not possible to expand the zip file because it is an unsupported format, obviously.... What do you mean it's an unsupported format? Try changing timeout from 10 to 100 in the second code...

I mean because in the function I've called downloadOriginal() it's taking a zip file (already compressed) and applying base64 encoding, so I wouldn't expect it to be a supported format? I can open the zip file when I download it without encoding to base64 but it takes longer to initiate the download

Compression shouldn't matter at all, when using base64.  It is supported. I  think you should change data:application/pdf; to data:application/zip; in the url - that maybe the issue...(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) PS: when you reply, use @ to notify the other user like @TheMaster

Hi @TheMaster I've tried changing to /zip same result. I only mentioned compression when using base64 because it resulted in a smaller file size (although I've since read that base64 can also lead to larger file sizes). I don't really understand why the zip file gets smaller with base64 (although not hugely), or why base64 is quicker to download. I thought there might be a simple answer but there doesn't appear to be. I'll just leave the timeout at 5000 instead of 10, and simply download the zip file with no encoding

FYI I also tried getting rid of base64 encoding and just having data:application/zip and it downloaded fast but hugely compressed (1.1MB to 80B). It was again an unsupported format.

Maybe the zip file fails to download fully because of 10s timeout... if you increase the timeout to say 100s, does the file size increase? Also, could  you open the file with a text editor like vim to see the bare(hex) data- to know whether it is the same file's first part?(base64 encoding is needed for binary data like zip inside data: urls,  otherwise it will surely fail inside data: urls)
