What is the purpose of the "access_token=" parameter when downloading a file from Google Drive?
My goal is to understand whether I need to include the "access_token=" parameter when downloading a file from Google Drive.
This is a sub-question from my overall aim is of creating a Google Apps Script function to download a zip file directly to my local device.
This answer to a related question provides two solutions, the first from Tanaike adds the parameter to the URL:
+ "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
and the second, from TheMaster includes it in the fetch headers:
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }, });
However, it is not required - the file downloads fine without it - so I'm wondering what purpose it serves and, therefore, if I should include it?

An access token gives a user (the resource owner) permission to access specific resources. On the other hand HTTP requests are sent to URLs using the UrlFetch API and HTTP requests and receive responses.

Access token is required when the file is private. Access token, as the name suggests, gives the owner of the token, access to a resource. If no special access is needed to access the file, access token is not required.
