# How to pop up print window via script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing

i have a script that selects a range when i click on a button

```
function selectRange() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SheetName').getRange("Range").activate()
  }
```

Now i'm looking is there somehow to pop up Google Sheets print window via script without clicking on print icon after the the script above is ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because Google Apps Script doesn't include methods to do such thing.

There are available two classes, Browser and Ui, that have effects on the Google Sheets user interface but either of them includes a method to open the Google Sheets print dialog.

Related

- [google app script print button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11194291/1595451)