# Automatically print a selected range in a google sheet with app script when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, printing

I'd like to kow it if it is possible to print the selected range when user click on a rectangular shape (button). I haven't been able to find anything on the GAS reference.

I found  some guys are using an html file to copy the content of their google sheet and then using PDF functions, but I think this is very complex because ths sheet has styles and all that.

Do you know a way to do this? Thanks !!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a print button of Google files in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194291/how-to-create-a-print-button-of-google-files-in-a-web-application) Apparently, Google Apps Script has no feature to print any google sheet directly. You may want to convert it to pdf instead and then print it.